# How Laravel handles PHP warnings?

Tags: php, laravel, exception, ldap

I'm trying to connect to a LDAP server using Laravel. It is important to say that I'm using the PHP functions `ldap_connect` and `ldap_bind` instead of using a package to handle it.

The point is that when I provide wrong user and password, the `ldap_bind` function gives to us a PHP warning. I'm OK with this warning and, as is in the documentation, the function returns **false** when the bind does not occur.

But, Laravel is throwing an exception when this warning is triggered. This is not an exception, Laravel should not throw an exception and I wouldn't like to handle this as an exception; I just have to build an `if` condition that will return a message to the user.

Does Laravel catch all warnings as an Exception?

Comment: If a specific exception is thrown, you can override its handler to behave differently than the default. See [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#the-exception-handler) from the Laravel Docs. What's the exception class?

Comment: @IlkerMutlu The class is ErrorException. This is also weird because it is a generic exception.

Comment: Then what you could do is wrap the ```ldap_bind``` call in a try catch block.

Comment: @IlkerMutlu I did it! But the point is that a simple PHP file does not throw an Exception. Why Laravel does? And, as I said above, the thrown exception is so generic!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the intended behavior for Laravel. Laravel will turn any error into an `ErrorException` instance. Here's the `bootstrap()` method inside the [`Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php#L27-L42) class.

```
public function bootstrap(Application $app)
{
    $this->app = $app;

    error_reporting(-1);

    set_error_handler([$this, 'handleError']);

    set_exception_handler([$this, 'handleException']);

    register_shutdown_function([$this, 'handleShutdown']);

    if (! $app->environment('testing')) {
        ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
    }
}
```

The `error_reporting(-1);` will set PHP to report all errors (read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)).

While this part of code:

```
set_error_handler([$this, 'handleError']);
```

Will set a custom error handler. If you check the `handleError()` method, it's pretty clear that Laravel will turn any error into an `ErrorException` instance.

```
public function handleError($level, $message, $file = '', $line = 0, $context = [])
{
    if (error_reporting() & $level) {
        throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $level, $file, $line);
    }
}
```

Read more about user-defined error handler [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

Hope this clear things up. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly the reason because I didn't write it but I assume having it work this way makes logging much easier.

Warnings get logged in php's error log but it's not possible to pass additional information along with it as context.

If that warning gets turned into an exception though, then you can pass the exception to the logger as well as other information such as the route which was hit, the request variables, etc... and log everything together.  You also get to dictate the severity of the issue by designating it as log, debug, info, notice, warning, error, critical, alert, and emergency and through monolog, handle each of those as you see fit.  This creates a log which is much easier to read and makes your code much easier to debug.

Additionally, as others have pointed out, it also allows you to do your work in try catch blocks which I believe also creates neater and cleaner code than trying to check if some variable `=== false`