# Try catch not working in Laravel 5.6 when a number is divided by zero

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, exception, php-7

Try catch block can not prevent run time exception in my Laravel code.
I wrote following code to test the exception handling:

```
try{
    $a=112/0;
}catch(Exception $e){
    $a=99;
}
```

But it returns a Run time error. Please help me to solve the issue.
[image: Run time exception]

Comment: It's a warning, not an exception. Run a simple test `if ($dividor === 0) { $a = 99; }`

Comment: @Qirel then why this solution worked for me ? try{
      $a=112/0;
     }catch(\Exception $e){
      $a=99;
     }

Comment: @HafijurRahmanSakib Because Laravel turns all PHP warnings into ErrorException Instance. Check this out: [Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php#L27-L42)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
try{
    $a=112/0;
}catch(\Exception $e){
    $a=99;
}
```

Notice the `\` before `Exception`.

**Update:** As @Qirel suggests:

You can simply update your code to do it without try/catch:

```
if($d === 0){
    $a = 99;
} else{
    $a = 112/$d
}
```

Comment: You can't do it with a try/catch to begin with, because its not an exception.

Comment: @Qirel Looks like, in case of Laravel, you can. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40548258/how-laravel-handles-php-warnings

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using php7 you need to use [Throwable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php) to catch the exception like this:

```php
try{
    $a=112/0;
}catch(Exception $e){
    // For php 5
    $a=99;
} catch(\Throwable $e) {
// For php7
    $a=99;
}
```