# Laravel get error type (E_ERROR, E_WARNING, etc)

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel v8. Is it possible to get the actual error type, as per the error constants in PHP? https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

I am trying to distinguish between fatal and non-fatal errors.

I am not using any custom error handler - just the one built in with Laravel.

I have tried the following in `\app\Exceptions\Handler.php`:

```
public function render($request, Throwable $e)
{
    $error = error_get_last();

    $type = $error['type']; // returns int or null

    if ($type == 1) {
        // do stuff here
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

But it seems `error_get_last()` is always returning null.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40548258/how-laravel-handles-php-warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here. Since I am only really interested in finding out if an error was a fatal/non-fatal, the following works perfectly:

```
public function render($request, Throwable $e)
{
    $fatal = $e instanceof \Error; // (returns boolean)

    if ($fatal) {
        // do stuff here
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```